# execute a command on a folder in the file system

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am doing this [maven eclipse hibernate spring-mvc tutorial](http://fruzenshtein.com/setup-of-dynamic-web-project-using-maven/), and I do not understand how to do step 3.  I have opened the project's root folder in the file system, but I do not know how to run a command in that folder, let alone the specified command.  Can anyone show me how to do this?

Here is the relevant portion of step 3 from the tutorial, which you can also read in the tutorial itself, if that is more informative:

```
3. Open the project’s root folder in the file system
    ◾Execute the following command: mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
    ◾This command will generate a configuration for eclipse (.classpath, .project, etc.).
```

---

### ANSWER:

[This link](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/ice-gt/339) contains the information I was looking for when I posted this question. It briefly describes how to change directories in the command prompt.

Comment: You need to open a command prompt.

Comment: Add Maven to your path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open a command line prompt, go to the project root folder and type :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  When I run the command at the specified folder in the command prompt, I get the message 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.  Can you tell me how to fix this so that the command executes properly?

Comment: you have to install maven. check this: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: I have the maven plugin for eclipse installed and am using that.  Is that not enough?  Also, will free standing maven and the plugin cooperate with each other?

Comment: in order to create project for eclipse you have to do it from command line with maven. eclipse plugin is using maven that you are going to install.